# Someone spamming car database?

Tags: support

I have seen several recent answers promoting https://car-database-api.com,
all of them by new users

User [nectarine](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/20556/nectarine), 4 answers (5 recommendations):

https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/13513/4293  (15 Oct 2018)
https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/13496/4293  (9 Nov 2018)
https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/13480/4293  (6 Nov 2018)

User [aggregator](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/19551/aggregator), 1 answer (2 recommendations):

https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/12915/4293  (4 Jun 2018)

User [java-warrior](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/19550/java-warrior), 1 answer (1 recommendation):

https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/12914/4293  (4 Jun 2018)

I'm getting suspicious, but it's not enough to flag them as spam.
Is further inquiry possible and necessary?

I have not yet commented asking for possible affiliation.

Answer (score 1):

Good find Jan. I've "protected" the upvoted question ([one](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/6390/1511), [two](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1664/1511)) in the meantime, to prevent new users from answering.

Yeah, sort of grey area regarding spam. Either way, we should downvote until they are hidden - because there is no actual open data and the answers are low quality (basically link only).

And the authors *must* disclose affiliation, so please add that as comments.

Mod Note: I can add that users 2 and 3 have IPs that resolve to the same Eastern European country. The first user has a geo-scattered IP.

Comment: Left a comment under the first answer.

Comment: What's a *geo-scattered IP*? My Google-fu fails... You mean an IP that's known as a VPN exit server?

Comment: I just made it up. As a mod I can lookup IP (my activity is recorded), and the first user had an IP that isn't clearly defined to one geographical region (each lookup provider gives a different answer).

Comment: User nectarine responded and seems legit https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6390/any-apis-available-that-provide-data-of-indian-vehicles/13496?noredirect=1#comment17301_13496.